# VS2017 node.js app web.config iisnode unrecognized

Tags: node.js, azure, express, visual-studio-2017

I have an existing node.js Express4 web application written in Visual Studio 2017 with the default Azure Express4 Node.js web app template.  I had modified the  entry in the web.config so that all of my folders were being watched for changes.  This was all working fine and I just noticed that my site is no longer restarting when I upload new files, and when I go to the web.config the iisnode entry in Visual Studio I see it is underlined with a message that says

> The element 'system.webserver' has invalid child element 'iisnode'.
>   List of possible elements expected: 'asp, caching, cgi
>   defaultDocument...'

I just accepted the Visual Studio update to 15.6.2 and can only guess that this has something to do with that as it was working fine last week before accepting that update.  Any clues?